# assign to variable of struct through property

Tags: vb.net, properties, variable-assignment

I have the following

```
Public Structure Foo
   dim i as integer
End Structure

Public Class Bar

Public Property MyFoo as Foo
Get
   return Foo
End Get
Set(ByVal value as Foo)
   foo  = value
End Set

dim foo as Foo    
End Class

Public Class Other

   Public Sub SomeFunc()    
     dim B as New Bar()    
     B.MyFoo = new Foo()    
     B.MyFoo.i = 14 'Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment ???    
   End Sub
End Class
```

My question is, why can I not assign to i through my property in the Bar class?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: very odd, not the behaviour I was expecting

Comment: The protection/accesibility level of `i` is relavant but I agree not the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76435b93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it says the following:

```
' Assume this code runs inside Form1.
Dim exitButton As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
exitButton.Text = "Exit this form"
exitButton.Location.X = 140
' The preceding line is an ERROR because of no storage for Location.
```

> The last statement of the preceding
>   example fails because it creates only
>   a temporary allocation for the Point
>   structure returned by the Location
>   property. A structure is a value type,
>   and the temporary structure is not
>   retained after the statement runs. The
>   problem is resolved by declaring and
>   using a variable for Location, which
>   creates a more permanent allocation
>   for the Point structure. The following
>   example shows code that can replace
>   the last statement of the preceding
>   example.

This is because the struct is only a temporary variable. So the solution is to create a new struct of the type you need, assign it all it's internal variables and then assign that struct to the struct property of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
Dim b as New Bar()
Dim newFoo As New Foo()
newFoo.i = 14
b.MyFoo = newFoo
```

To work around the problem.

Trying the same in C# with the code

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo = new Foo();
        bar.foo.i = 14;
        //You get, Cannot modify the return value of ...bar.foo
        //    because it is not a variable
    }
}
struct Foo
{
    public int i { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}
```

Which I think, is a more direct way of saying the same thing as

```
Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment
```